# Achemso package doesn't display my references

Tags: achemso

I'm trying to compile my achemso document, and add the references, it ran the first time, but it doesn't run anymore.
I'm a newbie and I have been hours reading several questions, and tried several things but it just doesn't work.

I tried running PDFlatex -> Bibtex -> PDFlatex
I tried deleting the aux file first and do the above.
I created a small document as the one I'm attaching but I cant see what is wrong.

Please help me! What I'm doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[journal=ancac3,manuscript=article]{achemso} 
\title{Achemso Template} 
\SectionNumbersOn
\begin{document} 


\begin{abstract} 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam 
\end{abstract} 

\maketitle

\section{Introduction} 

\section{Section} 

\subsection{this is the subsection} 

In 2016 \cite{ref1} 

\bibliography{myreferences}

\end{document}
```

In my bib file I have

```
@Article{ref1,   
author = {Mr Latex},  
title = {blablabla},    
year = {2016}}
```

and when I run the bibtex:

I get the message:

```
Process started

Need exactly one file argument

Process exited normally
```

Not sure what is happening.

this is the log:

LOG FILE :

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.11.6) 20 FEB 2017 11:29
entering extended mode
**./test.tex
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\achemso\achemso.cls"
Document Class: achemso 2017/01/21 v3.10h Submission to ACS journals
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\keyval.tex"))
\XKV@depth=\count87
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
\acs@bib@file=\write3
\c@bibnote=\count88
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty"
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count89
\Gm@cntv=\count90
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count91
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen103
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen104
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen105
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen106
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen107
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen108
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen109
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen110
\Gm@dimlist=\toks16
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\caption\caption.sty"
Package: caption 2016/02/21 v3.3-144 Customizing captions (AR)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\caption\caption3.sty"
Package: caption3 2016/05/22 v1.7-166 caption3 kernel (AR)
Package caption3 Info: TeX engine: e-TeX on input line 67.
\captionmargin=\dimen111
\captionmargin@=\dimen112
\captionwidth=\dimen113
\caption@tempdima=\dimen114
\caption@indent=\dimen115
\caption@parindent=\dimen116
\caption@hangindent=\dimen117
)
\c@ContinuedFloat=\count92
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\float\float.sty"
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count93
\float@exts=\toks17
\float@box=\box26
\@float@everytoks=\toks18
\@floatcapt=\box27
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2016/07/10 v0.06j Graphics/color for pdfTeX
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count94
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen118
\Gin@req@width=\dimen119
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\setspace\setspace.sty"
Package: setspace 2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty"
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16 ver 3.4 Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\acs@author@cnt=\count95
\acs@affil@cnt=\count96
\acs@affil@alt@cnt=\count97
\acs@footnote@cnt=\count98
\acs@affil@marker@cnt=\count99
\acs@space@pre@title=\skip43
\acs@space@post@title=\skip44
\acs@space@post@author=\skip45
\acs@space@post@address=\skip46
\acs@space@post@email=\skip47
\acs@maketitle@width=\skip48
\@float@every@scheme=\toks19
\c@scheme=\count100
\@float@every@chart=\toks20
\c@chart=\count101
\@float@every@graph=\toks21
\c@graph=\count102
\@float@every@table=\toks22
\acs@collect@toks=\toks23
\acs@collect@empty@toks=\toks24
\acs@tocentry@height=\skip49
\acs@tocentry@width=\skip50
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\achemso\achemso-ancac3.cfg"
File: achemso-ancac3.cfg 2017/01/21 v3.10h achemso configuration: ACS Nano
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\natbib\natbib.sty"
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip51
\bibsep=\skip52
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count103
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\achemso\natmove.sty"
Package: natmove 2010/01/15 v1.1a Automatic citation moving with natbib
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mciteplus\mciteplus.sty"
Package: mciteplus 2013/09/13 v1.2 enhanced mcite
\@mcitetmptoksA=\toks25
\@mcitetmpdima=\dimen120
\@mcitetmpdimb=\dimen121
\@mcitetmpcnta=\count104
\@mcitetmpcntb=\count105
\c@mcitebibitemcount=\count106
\c@mcitesubitemcount=\count107
** mciteplus: Detected natbib.sty. Invoking hooks.
)) (test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
\openout3 = `acs-test.bib'.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes:
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.2698pt, 469.75539pt, 72.2698pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.2698pt, 650.43037pt, 72.2698pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=469.75539pt
* \textheight=650.43037pt
* \oddsidemargin=-0.00018pt
* \evensidemargin=-0.00018pt
* \topmargin=-37.00018pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=12.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=44.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.8pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: float package is loaded.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count108
\scratchdimen=\dimen122
\scratchbox=\box28
\nofMPsegments=\count109
\nofMParguments=\count110
\everyMPshowfont=\toks26
\MPscratchCnt=\count111
\MPscratchDim=\dimen123
\MPnumerator=\count112
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count113
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks27
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty"
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty"
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds) That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds) that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds) In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
38.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext) [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext) \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.
)
Class achemso Warning: No affiliations: at least one affiliation is needed on i
nput line 4.
Class achemso Warning: No e-mail given:
(achemso) at lest one author must have a contact e-mail on input l
ine 4.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <12> on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <8> on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <6> on input line 4.
Package natbib Warning: Citation `ref1' on page 1 undefined on input line 19.
No file test.bbl.
Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.
[1
{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (test.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
4384 strings out of 493334
67802 string characters out of 3139246
132990 words of memory out of 3000000
7861 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
10360 words of font info for 36 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
60i,4n,94p,258b,256s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program F
iles/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiK
TeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/
fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx8.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/typ
e1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public
/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
/cm/cmss12.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss
bx10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 70155 bytes).
PDF statistics:
34 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Welcome, please show the log and blg file of this test case.

Comment: I've added the log file.

Comment: And the more imortant blg file? Did you run BibTeX?

Comment: Yes, when i run bibtex i get: Process started

Need exactly one file argument

Process exited normally (Is this what you mean with the blg file?